# Angular - How to render single quote from string variable

Tags: angular

I'm sure this must be a duplicate but I can't find an existing question/answer.

I have a variable with some content inluding an escaped single quote:

`someString: 'We\'ll be back soon'`

I am adding it to the page like so:

`<p>{{ someString }}</p>`

The resulting string when the component is rendered is:

`We&#39;ll be back soon`

How do I get it to render the expected string without converting the single quote?

`We'll be back soon`

Comment: Use double quotes when give value to the variable: `someString="We'll be back soon"`

Comment: @Eliseo I have also tried this approach to no avail, plus the ts settings and linter would not allow it.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this with just a <p> tag: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b8pvi8?file=src/app/app.component.html. It is probably not the linter or ts settings that doesn't allow double quotes, rather the auto-formatter on your IDE.

Comment: Yeah I have also tried it on stackblitz and it worked as expected... The real code is a lot more complex than the example I gave in the question, the variable is passed to the component through a configuration. I'm also testing this through Storybook. Must be something weird going on in project. I'll have to do some digging, thanks for looking into it :)

Comment: If you read the variable from a file, check if the file is save as utf8, unicode,...

Comment: It is written in a typescript configuration so not loaded from a file, it gets passed around a few components before being rendered so something weird must be going on or for some reason it's being converted to HTML and then Angular is inserting it as a string.

Comment: So it turns out there was an escaping conversion happening in our code, had to use a pipe to unescape the value. `<p>{{ someString | unescape }}</p>`.